# Anaconda & Tensorflow & Skflow: dnn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep_prob'

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

When running this example in Anaconda 2.7:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
def DNN_model(X, y):
    """This is DNN with 50, 20, 10 hidden layers, and dropout of 0.5 probability."""
    layers = skflow.ops.dnn(X, [50, 30, 10], keep_prob=0.5)
    return skflow.models.logistic_regression(layers, y)
clf = skflow.TensorFlowEstimator(model_fn=DNN_model, n_classes=3)
```

It dumps the following problem:

> dnn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep_prob'

Tensorflow in Anaconda was installed using:

```
conda install -c jjhelmus tensorflow=0.9.0
```

Any idea what failed?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/ops/dnn_ops.py) it seems this version is depreciated:

`learn.ops.dnn is deprecated,please use contrib.layers.dnn.`

However, different arguments should be passed:

```
def dnn(tensor_in, hidden_units, activation=nn.relu, dropout=None):
  """Creates fully connected deep neural network subgraph.
  This is deprecated. Please use contrib.layers.dnn instead.
  Args:
    tensor_in: tensor or placeholder for input features.
    hidden_units: list of counts of hidden units in each layer.
    activation: activation function between layers. Can be None.
    dropout: if not None, will add a dropout layer with given probability.
  Returns:
    A tensor which would be a deep neural network.
  """
```